# Interitance in argument type of an interface

Tags: java

I am trying to have an base implementation of a request as an argument type of an interface's function.

And then have various classes extend the base request class to give more specific meaning to the request object.

But Java needs the exact class as argument and does not honor classes extended by that base class.

```
public interface MyInterface{
   public String getValue(BaseRequest req);
}

public class MyInterfaceImpl implements MyInterface{
   public String getValue(SpecificRequest req){ //Java will give a compile error here.
      //Impl
   }
}

public interface BaseRequest{
   int requiredA;
   int requiredB;
   //setter and getters for A and B
}

public class SpecificRequest extends BaseRequest{
   int specificValC;
   //setter and getters for C
}
```

What is the best way to achieve this pattern? Or I am designing a little too much?

Comment: what is the point of MyInterface in this situation?  you could never call MyInterface.getValue() as you have to know the more specific implementation in order to invoke the method.

Comment: Well, in my own naive mind, it doesn't surprise me that you get a compile error. Keep in mind the interface declaration is a contract of sorts, and the getValue implementation doesn't exactly honor the contract. Now, if you made BaseRequest an abstract class rather than an interface that might solve the problem and, actually slightly more accurately reflect the problem you're modeling. Good luck.

Comment: @DavidW - how does making BaseRequest an abstract class change anything?

Comment: @jtahlborn - *sigh* I guess, in retrospect, it doesn't. I think I was mentally going a different direction when I originally read the problem. Point taken.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can achieve something similar using generics.

```
public interface MyInterface<R extends BaseRequest> {
   public String getValue(R req);
}

public class MyInterfaceImpl implements MyInterface<SpecificRequest> {
   public String getValue(SpecificRequest req){ 
      //Impl
   }
}
```

Comment: Now that you've opened Pandora's box, we can expect a further stream of questions from OP tagged `java-generics` :)

Comment: Me too. Great answer. Dang it :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're declaring your interface as the one accepting `BaseRequest` java won't let you narrow it down to just some `SpecificRequest`, these are the basics of OOP.
If you really need this interface you should show us examples of other implementations of your interface that you're going to create. I mean it's hard to see the point of your design to tell if you're doing it too much.

Comment: Yeah I understand that won't work. My question was if I need a similar class structure, what is the pragmatic way (some pattern?) to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

When you implement an interface, compiler makes sure that your implementation is true to the declaration, i.e. you can not narrow down a parameter type to a derived class.

However, you can pass in a derived class:

```
   public class MyInterfaceImpl implements MyInterface {
       public String getValue(BaseRequest req){ 
           // ...
       }
   }

   ... 
   // calling your method
   MyInterface provider = ...
   SpecificRequest request = ...
   provider.getValue(request);
```